# How specific can landlords be regarding Covid-19?

Tags: landlord, covid-19

Are there any privacy protections which would prevent a landlord from including the name of a specific tenant in a warning regarding Covid-19?

For context: Recently my partner and I (we live in Massachusetts) started exhibiting symptoms of Covid-19. After speaking with a doctor, we informed our landlord that we may be ill. He responded by saying that he has to inform other residents of our building that we are ill. While we agree that it is important for other residents to be aware and take extra precautions, we are concerned about our landlord including our names (particularly given that my partner is Asian-American).

Comment: Why did you tell your landlord?

Comment: @DaleM So that he could let other residents be aware that they need to take extra precautions. Some were still inviting friends over. We, like everyone, have public health responsibilities.

Comment: @Tom See https://www.mass.gov/info-details/frequently-asked-questions-about-covid-19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### He can tell the world

You chose to tell him. He has no duty of confidence with you (he is not your health professional) so he can tell whoever he likes however he likes.